# XSD validates wrong format of xs:date and xs:dateTime

Tags: xml, xsd

When I set the **year** section like below (20512 or anything like this), XSD still validates XML.

Any idea.

Is this a flaw or do I have to use **simpleType** with given pattern?

Thanks

**XSD**

```
<xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:date" />

<xs:attribute name="timestamp" type="xs:dateTime" />
```

**XML**

```
<store date="20512-07-11" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="items.xsd">

<store timestamp="20512-07-11T21:50:16" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="items.xsd">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **NOT** flaw in your validator (btw, you should indicate which validator you're using). Other validators (mis)behave the way you seem to expect; for e.g., .NET would complain `The value '20512-07-11' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:date' - The string '20512-07-11' is not a valid XsdDateTime value.`

See [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#deviantformats) of the XSD spec, section D3.3 which clearly states that your value is valid.

Comment: PHP I'm using, testing with both DOM and XMLReader. Result is same in all. I know that 20512 is not valid year. I did it deliberately to check if validation work fine.

Comment: @Max Max, just to clarify, I've added the link to the XSD spec. It clearly states that years greater than 9999 are allowed. Again, `it is a flaw in your validator`. The limitations (in my case), since the validator is based on .NET, it is bound to the limitations in .NET where the upper bound value for the year is 9999.

Comment: I decided to use simpleType with YYYY-MM-DD pattern so problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: It actually is not a flaw per se. Looking at the spec at: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime It says: "'-'? yyyy is a four-or-more digit optionally negative-signed numeral that represents the year; if more than four digits, leading zeros are prohibited, and '0000' is prohibited (see the Note above (§3.2.7); also note that a plus sign is not permitted);"    The sections for gYear and such also explicitly say that the year can be greater than 4 digits.

Comment: @ShawnFumo, not sure I get your comment and downvote; years greater that 9999 ARE allowed by the spec; any validator that complains about it HAS a flaw according to the schema spec.

Comment: @PetruGardea I'm sorry I misread your response, though you may have misread the original question. The question asks why 20512 is passing validation and if it is a flaw with their validator (in the title: "XSD  validates wrong format"). Then you said "It is a flaw in your validator" so I read your response as saying large years are invalid. I think inanzzz's validator is working correctly but not in the way they expected. It won't let me change my vote so I upvoted a diff answer of yours to compensate.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, but why do you consider 20512-07-11 to be an invalid date? Astronomers might be very keen to maintain data showing that an eclipse will occur on that date.

If you want to limit your dates to a particular range, e.g before the year 2100, then you should use a simpleType derived from xs:date that restricts the range of values using a maxExclusive facet.

Comment: We can come out with many IFs and BUTs so 20512-07-11 is not a realistic date that's why. If I get a date like that, I would consider it as a genuine mistake or joke so I have eliminate it. Humans might move to another planet before 5 digits(YYYYY) and start everything from scratch like the syntax of date:) God bless all!

Comment: You might also consider 1750-12-15 to be an unrealistic date. Others wouldn't. XML Schema is designed to meet the needs of a wide class of users. It doesn't know what range of dates you consider realistic; you do. Making the cutoff be the year 9999 seems highly arbitrary to me.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelKay that there's nothing inherently invalid about the year 20512 (though your language/validator may have limitations). If you have business rules that limit "realistic" dates to a precise time period you would expect to have to apply those on top of any basic data structures (e.g. if it was a 4 digit year, you'd still consider orders for the year 7812 invalid, and probably even for 2112).